# How to use a newly started WCF service ASAP

Tags: wcf

In my application I have to manually start an executable. This executable acts as a server and starts a WCF service but the whole initialization process takes time. In my client (that has created the new process) I have to use the WCF service **ASAP**.

So I check every 100ms that the service has started by calling a Ping() method of the service. The first call throws EndPointNotFoundException which I handle. But the second call throws CommunicationObjectFaultedException. I've checked and after I handle the EndPointNotFoundException the state of the CommunicationObject which I use to create the client proxy is Opened. Is my approach wrong and how should check whether the service is started?

UPDATE1: This is how I start the WCF service:

```
ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService));
const string address = "net.pipe://localhost/testservice";
Binding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestService), binding, address);

serviceHost.Open();
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

UPDATE2: This is how I create the proxy:

```
ChannelFactory<ITestService> channelFactory =
        new ChannelFactory<ITestService>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "net.pipe://localhost/testservice");
_testServiceProxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

And this is how I ping the service:

```
private static bool IsServiceAvailable(ITestService serviceProxy)
{
    const int maxNumberOfTries = 100;
    const int timeout = 100;
    bool isServiceAvailable = false;
    int numberOfTries = 0;

    do
    {
        Thread.Sleep(timeout);
        try
        {
            serviceProxy.Ping();
            isServiceAvailable = true;
        }
        catch (EndpointNotFoundException)
        {}
        numberOfTries++;

        if (numberOfTries > maxNumberOfTries)
            break;
    }
    while (!isServiceAvailable);

    return isServiceAvailable;
}
```

Comment: Does your service implements metadata endpoint (mex)?

Comment: I am fairly new to WCF and I am updating my question to show how I start the WCF service. Anyway - I don't think it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due the fact that you cannot reuse a faulted proxy, you should create a new one.

```
private static bool IsServiceAvailable(ChannelFactory<ITestService> channelFactory)
{
    const int maxNumberOfTries = 100;
    const int timeout = 100;
    bool isServiceAvailable = false;
    int numberOfTries = 0;

    do
    {
        Thread.Sleep(timeout);
        try
        {
            using(var proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel())
                proxy.Ping();

            isServiceAvailable = true;
        }
        catch (EndpointNotFoundException)
        {}
        numberOfTries++;

        if (numberOfTries > maxNumberOfTries)
            break;
    }
    while (!isServiceAvailable);

    return isServiceAvailable;
}
```

Comment: I already stated that after the first Ping() call the state of the communication object is Opened. It faults during the second Ping() call.

Comment: I am now writing tests and seems to be OK for now. I am not sure how I should close the proxies though.

Answer (score 3):

The .NET framework has a namespace called [System.ServiceModel.Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.aspx) which has some classes which may be useful for your use case. Specifically the [AnnouncementClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.announcementclient.aspx) class which allows a service to publish announcement messages. From the documentation:

> An announcement message contains information about the service such as its fully-qualified contract name, any scopes that the service is operating in as well as any custom metadata the service wants to send.

As far as being able to know when the service is online, this class has a mechanism for that. From the documentation:

> If a service adds the ServiceDiscoveryBehavior behavior and specifies an AnnouncementEndpoint the service automatically sends announcement messages when the service goes online or comes offline. Use this class when you want to explicitly send the announcement messages yourself.

The methods that provide the support you are looking for are: `AnnounceOnline` and `AnnounceOffline` which you can use to message your client about the state of your service. This would allow your client to be informed by the service when it is ready removing the need for a ping in a loop.